# Use Android as a remote control for Inves TV

Tags: applications, remote-control, television

I have an INVES LED-3214 FHD GR television (manufactured by ElCorteIngles - Spain) and I can't find its remote control.

I downloaded several Universal Remote Control (infrared remote control) applications from Google Play on my phone, but it asks me to choose the brand and Inves does not appear.

Can something be done to use an Android application for this TV?

Comment: So your Android phone has a built-in IR connector (not very common for Android phones)? Because otherwise the only way to control to control the TV via Wifi. If a TV brand is not listed it usually does not produce the TVs, instead use other manufacturers create the TVs and just label them as their own.